# How can I make this modal close onMouseLeave in my Reactjs application, styled with Material UI

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui

I have a modal that opens onMouseEnter which works great, however, I'm having trouble closing it onMouseLeave when the user stops hovering over the button.

Here is my component:

I've tried adding an event listener, onMouseLeave to the button tag, but it does not work correctly.  Any ideas?

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Modal from '@material-ui/core/Modal';
import Backdrop from '@material-ui/core/Backdrop';
import Fade from '@material-ui/core/Fade';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  modal: {
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  paper: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
    border: '2px solid #000',
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[5],
    padding: theme.spacing(2, 4, 3),
  },
}));

const DistributionLineOverflow = props => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button type="button" onMouseEnter={handleOpen}>
        i
      </button>
      <Modal
        aria-labelledby="transition-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="transition-modal-description"
        className={classes.modal}
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        closeAfterTransition
        BackdropComponent={Backdrop}
        BackdropProps={{
          timeout: 500,
        }}
      >
        <Fade in={open}>
          <div className={classes.paper}>
            <p id="transition-modal-description">
              Service Dates: {props.serviceDates}
            </p>
          </div>
        </Fade>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DistributionLineOverflow;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button
        onMouseEnter={() => handleOpen()}
        onMouseLeave={() => handleClose()}
      >
        i
      </button>
      <div
        style={{
          width: 500,
          height: 500,
          backgroundColor: "blue",
          display: open ? "block" : "none"
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Try calling your methods like this instead.

I created a code sandbox with similar behaviour: https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-meninsky-7fl2o

I updated the codesandbox link, but it seems that codesandbox is having some problem running it for me so I have posted the whole code here as well.

Comment: The sandbox link does not seem to be working, can you check and see the sandbox is still valid? I'd like to see how you've implemented it. Changing the way the methods are being called to what you're proposing doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: I updated my asnwer hopefully it can help @ghostagent151

Comment: This shows a div, not modal that would be attached over the button you are getting the event from. A modal will prevent all underlying mouse events from being fired. 

As this example shows, we are just showing and adding a sibling div, which would not change the mouse events for sibling button.